# Time ago function accuracy

Tags: php, date

I have a function in which gets the date from a post and is supposed to write how long ago it was posted. When I use the function it says it was posted 43 years and 4 months ago for some odd reason.

```
function relativeTime($date,$precision=2)
{
$times=array(365*24*60*60   => "year",
            30*24*60*60     => "month",
            7*24*60*60      => "week",
            24*60*60        => "day",
            60*60           => "hour",
            60              => "minute",
            1               => "second");

$passed=time()-$date;

if($passed<5)
{
    $output='less than 5 seconds ago';
}
else
{
    $output=array();
    $exit=0;
    foreach($times as $period=>$name)
    {
        if($exit>=$precision || ($exit>0 && $period<60))    break;
        $result = floor($passed/$period);

        if($result>0)
        {
            $output[]=$result.' '.$name.($result==1?'':'s');
            $passed-=$result*$period;
            $exit++;
        }

        else if($exit>0) $exit++;

    }
    $output=implode(' and ',$output).' ago';
}

return $output;
}
```

I am entering the date using:
`$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

Is the `$passed=time()-$date` off?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` as the input, which will return something akin to `2013-05-13 02:04:05` right now. The call to `time()` will currently return a value near `1368403494`. Subtract the two from eachother, and the date string will be implicitly silently converted to an integer by PHP, so `2013`. That means it'll see your post as about 1368403494 seconds ago, not entirely accidentally ending up somewhere in January 1970, the start of the Unix timestamp age. So yep, that'll be some 43 years and a few months old.

Don't mix string and integer arithmetic, PHP's silent conversions make them hell.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So are you suggesting using something other than time()?

Comment: No, you should definitely use `time()`, you just should stop comparing (and subtracting) apples and oranges. If you want to compare 2 times, make sure they're both timestamps, so call `strtotime` on your date first. You cannot subtract 5kg to 5km either, things have to be on the same scale for any arithmetic.

Comment: So this strtotime function will convert it to a number as in the time function?

Comment: [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php): *"Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp"*

Answer (score 2):

`time()` gives you a timestamp, i.e. an integer that represents the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

`date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` gives you a string, e.g. `2013-05-13 02:04:34`

When you subtract theses two values, the string is converted into an integer based on the initial characters of the string. This yields 2013, which does not affect the timestamp very much.

Use a common format for the input paramter and the value that you want to subtract it from. When doing calculations on time instances, timestamps are usually easier to handle than any string formats (which are for presentation, not calculation). I'd change the function definition to accept timestamps.

Comment: Oh so thsts where the 43 years comes from. Should I try taking the Y-m-d out?

Comment: Change the format in which your function expects the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There's a *much* better way to do this. Use [DateTime and its associated classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). The code is simpler and more accurate because it takes time zones and daylight's savings time into account.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2013-01-03 17:13:00');
$interval  = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$elapsed   = $interval->format('%y years, %m months, %a days, %h hours, 
                              %i minutes, %S seconds');
$elapsed = str_replace(array('0 years,', ' 0 months,', ' 0 days,', 
                            ' 0 hours,', ' 0 minutes,'), '', $elapsed);
$elapsed = str_replace(array('1 years, ', ' 1 months, ', ' 1 days, ', 
                             ' 1 hours, ', ' 1 minutes'), array('1 year, ', 
                             '1 month, ', ' 1 day, ', ' 1 hour, ', ' 1 minute'), 
                       $elapsed);
echo $elapsed;
```

Comment: Thank you very much I shall try that out